# Selecting a <path> d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to select a path inside a  class.

I am trying to use the following code to select the path but instead selects a line or all the lines. I am trying to select the line class "line_series_2" that is inside "lines" class but everything I have tried so far does not work.

Here is the fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/zvkgs5s4/4/

```
 //The data for our line
 var lineData = [ { "x": 1,   "y": 5},  { "x": 20,  "y": 20},
                  { "x": 40,  "y": 10}, { "x": 60,  "y": 40},
                  { "x": 80,  "y": 5},  { "x": 100, "y": 60}];

 //The data for our line
 var lineData2 = [ { "x": 20,   "y": 25},  { "x": 90,  "y": 20},
                  { "x": 54,  "y": 30}, { "x": 11,  "y": 40},
                  { "x": 23,  "y": 32},  { "x": 10, "y": 60}];


 //This is the accessor function we talked about above
 var lineFunction = d3.svg.line()
                          .x(function(d) { return d.x; })
                          .y(function(d) { return d.y; })
                         .interpolate("linear");


var graph = d3.select('svg')
      .append("svg:svg")
      .attr("class", "line-graph")
      .append("svg:g")

    // append a group to contain all lines
    var lines = graph.append("svg:g")
      .attr("class", "lines");

    lines.append("path")
        .attr("class", "line_series_1")
        .attr("d", lineFunction(lineData))
        .attr("stroke", "blue")
        .attr("stroke-width", 2)
        .attr("fill", "none");

      lines.append("path")
        .attr("class", "line_series_2")
        .attr("d", lineFunction(lineData2))
        .attr("stroke", "red")
        .attr("stroke-width", 2)
        .attr("fill", "none");


d3.selectAll("g .lines .line_series_1").select("path").attr('stroke-width', '6');
```

The following code will work but doesn't select class "the line_series_2"

```
d3.select("g .lines").select("path").attr('stroke-width', '6')
```

or

```
d3.selectAll("g .lines").select("path").attr('stroke-width', '6')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are overcomplicating your select.

Just make it:

```
d3.selectAll(".line_series_1").attr('stroke-width', '6');
```